# Accidentally deleted upperfilter in 4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318 and now external hard drives wont register

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

One of my external hard drives wasn't working so I tried a bunch of things to fix it and one thing said to delete upperfilters and lowerfilters in 4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318, so I did that. I later found out my chord was broken and that's why my HD wasn't working, but now my computer won't register that any hard drive is connected. It makes the sound like it is connected and the drives light up, they also show up in device manager, but they don't show up in disk management. I don't know what to do. I'm also not a computer wiz, I was just following instructions, so the more simplistic or at least well-instructed answer the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UpperFilters and LowerFilters are two kinds of registry entries that link the operating system to different hardware pieces your computer has. Deleting them is always a mistake, because you don't know what you are actually removing and it's hard to undo what you deleted. So, the advice you followed was, as you can see, less than optimal.

Unless you noted somewhere the values for these two registry entries, they are lost forever. This means you have the following solutions:

1. **System Restore**. If it's activated, choose the latest restore point and hope all is not lost. If you have disabled it, then the next solution is:
2. **Reset the operating system**. The good part is that your external hard-drive will work. The bad part: it's the equivalent of a fresh install.

Personal advice: Windows is made with the normal user in mind (as you say you are) so, generally, if you have to tinker in places where you most of the time don't, then chances are what you want to do is reserved for more computer-savvy people. Next time, if you're not sure what you do, better not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are these USB drives?

If only external USB drives are affected, you can try reinstalling the root hub drivers and see if that resets things. Try this.

- If you are using a USB mouse or keyboard, and this is a laptop, switch to laptop trackpad/keyboard for a moment.
- Open Device Manager.
- Scroll all the way down to "Universal Serial Bus controllers."
- Expand it.
- Look for "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller" - it's possible but unlikely it may be non-Intel.
- Right click, Uninstall device.
- Leave "Delete the driver software for this device" UNchecked.
- Windows may ask you to restart.  Don't do that now.
- Do the same for any USB 2.0 controller or root hub - right click, uninstall, but don't delete driver software.
- Restart.
- On next boot Windows will redetect the USB hubs and reinstall the drivers.  It may want you to reboot again.

Now see if your USB hard drives are recognized properly.

If this doesn't work--or makes things worse--since you are using Windows 10, you may try the "Reset this PC" option (just type it in the search bar on the bottom) *after* backing up your files and other data.